# Create SSIS package to extract the word "NULL" to Excel file when the value is NULL in date fields

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

I have a SQL table containing fields with a mixture of formats. The customer requires the data in this table to be extracted to an Excel file, and wants the word "NULL" to appear in fields where there is a NULL. When using SSIS to extract data to Excel, it replaces NULLs with a blank. I can successfully replace NULLs with "NULL" for nvarchar columns using SSIS derived columns using the expression REPLACENULL(ColumnName,"NULL"). What is the expression for date and datetime columns? I want to write out the date to Excel if it is not null, and write the word "NULL" out if it is null. There has to be a simple way to do this, right? I've tried the following which does not work:

```
ISNULL(ColumnName) ? NULL(DT_DBDATE) : ColumnName
```

Comment: What does "does not work" mean?

Comment: @Larnu I mean that SSIS extracts the NULL out as a blank in the Excel file

Comment: So that value isn't actually a date, nor is it a `NULL`?

Comment: `NULL` isn't a word. It means there's no value at all. Not a blank, there's no value. I bet that Excel *doesn't* contain anything in that null cell. Not a blank, the cell is probably not saved at all in the `xlsx` file

Comment: Indeed, neither a date or a NULL is being extracted to Excel. Perhaps Excel is seeing it as a NULL and then converting to a blank. I would like SSIS to make  the NULL a text "NULL". However, as it is a date field, I';m not sure how to do this

Comment: Why do you want to insert some arbitrary text in that Excel field? There's no valid date value you can put there. Putting the string `NULL` will simply break any formulas and greatly annoy end users. And anyone who has to import that Excel sheet into another system. They'd have to *remove* that arbitrary string

Comment: What you have doesn't make sense anyway. It's saying that if the value is `NULL` return `NULL`, otherwise the value of the column.

Comment: @SpatialFrequency Excel works the way it should, and so does SSIS. Why do you want to replace a missing date value with an arbitrary string? At best you'd make formatting that Excel column a lot harder

Comment: It's what the customer wants and they won't be importing the data from the Excel sheet anywhere else.

Comment: I realise it's unusal query and despite the fact that it is not good practice to do this, is it actually possible?

Comment: You haven't explained what you want yet - or rather, you haven't realized what you ask. You want to replace a NULL date with what? The value/expression for missing dates **is** that NULL. If you want to replace it with a different date *value* you'll have to decide what that is. `0001-01-01`? `2000-01-01`? `9999-12-31`? If you want to emit a *string* like `NULL` you'll have to change the field type to string

Comment: isnull(convert(varchar(10), DateColumnName, 120),'NULL') as DateColumnName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I'm not on my mobile anymore, so I *think* I actually understand what you're after.

What you have right now, doesn't really make any sense. The expression `ISNULL(ColumnName) ? NULL(DT_DBDATE) : ColumnName` is **literally** equivalent to `ColumnName` (assuming `ColumnName` is the datatype `DT_DBDATE`).

What you need to do here is likely this:

```
ISNULL(ColumnName) ? "NULL" : (DT_WSTR,10) ColumnName
```

Note that this won't use a specific format, and will likely be based on your language settings. If you want a specific format, you need to build and cast the specific parts. For example the below would return the day in `dd` format:

```
RIGHT("00" & ((DT_WSTR,10) DAY(ColumnName)),2)
```

Personally, however, I recommend avoiding SSIS Expressions where you can, and using SQL to do the "heavy" lifting. Then you can return the `varchar` value you need, and use a style code for the `CONVERT`.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I will report back tomorrow if this solves my query. Your effort and time is much appreciated.

Comment: Perfect, this does exactly what I am after. Many thanks.